# How do I plot the intersection of two fit lines in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file that looks something like this:

```
# Test of 6
0.1 3.2 
0.4 5.9 
0.7 8.0 
0.9 10.1


0.1 1.5 
0.4 4.3 
0.7 9.5 
0.9 13.5

# Test of 10
0.1 5.5 
0.4 6.3 
0.7 6.9 
0.9 8.5 


0.1 0.5 
0.4 3.3 
0.7 8.5 
0.9 15.5

# Test of 15
0.1 12.5
0.4 13.3
0.7 13.5
0.9 15.5


0.1 1.5 
0.4 7.3 
0.7 15.5
0.9 16.5
```

I then use gnuplot to find the fit lines for each set, and the crossover point of the two fit lines:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'image.png'

unset key 

set xrange [0:20]
set yrange [0:1]

f(x) = a*x + b 
g(x) = c*x + d 

fit f(x) "data.dat" i 0 u 1:2 via a,b 
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 1 u 1:2 via c,d 
p1 = (d - b) / (a - c)
fit f(x) "data.dat" i 2 u 1:2 via a,b 
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 3 u 1:2 via c,d 
p2 = (d - b) / (a - c)
fit f(x) "data.dat" i 4 u 1:2 via a,b 
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 5 u 1:2 via c,d 
p3 = (d - b) / (a - c)

# what is the real way?
# set label at 6, p1 "" point pointtype 7 pointsize 2
# set label at 10, p2 "" point pointtype 7 pointsize 2
# set label at 15, p3 "" point pointtype 7 pointsize 2
# plot 1/0
```

I can use labels to set the points where i want them but i would really like to be able to find the fit line for these points. I think I could do that if I could treat (6,p1); (10,p2); (15,p3) as a data file. But how do I do that or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Gnuplot has named data blocks. You can both print to and plot from data blocks. Using the data from the question, the final plot file is:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'image.png'

unset key

set xrange [0:20]
set yrange [0:1]

f(x) = a*x + b
g(x) = c*x + d

fit f(x) "data.dat" i 0 u 1:2 via a,b
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 1 u 1:2 via c,d
p1 = (d - b) / (a - c)
fit f(x) "data.dat" i 2 u 1:2 via a,b
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 3 u 1:2 via c,d
p2 = (d - b) / (a - c)
fit f(x) "data.dat" i 4 u 1:2 via a,b
fit g(x) "data.dat" i 5 u 1:2 via c,d
p3 = (d - b) / (a - c)

set print $points
print 6,p1
print 10,p2
print 15,p3

fit f(x) $points u 1:2 via a,b
plot $points w p pt 7 ps 2, f(x)
```

This produces a png like this:
[image: Ermahgerd, it werks!]